# Python web scraping with regex

Tags: python, regex, web, beautifulsoup, scrape

Could someone assist me with a bit of code I'd like to build to pull stats from a game?
I can put the html into BeautifulSoup, but I don't know how to properly format the regex to get at the specific bit of data from the entire page.
Here's what I've got:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

content = urlopen('http://www.worldoftanks.com/community/accounts/1000395103-FrankenTank').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
print soup
```

If you could show me how to pull one stat out, I can figure out the rest.
One of the stats is Battles participated (10103), coded as below:

```
<tr>
<td class=""> Battles Participated: </td>
<td class="td-number-nowidth"> 10 103 </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks!

Frank

Comment: What do regular expressions have to do with this? You are using a proper HTML parser, you don't want to use regular expressions here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Searching the tree](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree):

```
battles = soup.find('td', 'td-number-nowidth')
if battles:
   print(battles.get_text())
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.   The stats all repeat using the same 'td-number-nowidth' code.  What method would you recommend to iterate to the next instance of that string?

Comment: @User: you could call soup.find_all() to get all results as a list.

Answer (score 0):

Does the number you want to pull out contain that space in between?  If so, I would do something that looks like this:

```
m = re.search('class="td-number-nowidth">(\d+) (\d+)</td>', soup)
if m:
    print(m.groups())
```

groups() returns a string `tuple` that will contain "10" and "103" so you may need to concatenate them together and either leave it as a `string` type or parse it into an `int` for your purposes.

```
matched = m.groups()
num = matched[0] + matched[1]
finalnumber = int(num)
```

Comment: I think the OP is not fully understanding that regular expressions are not needed when you use BeautifulSoup (a proper HTML parser).

Comment: I now see regex wasn't needed.  very cool.   Rarehunter your code failed for me.  Likely my 2.7 version of python was the problem.  Thank you all for the instructions here.  (what's an OP?)

Comment: OP stands for "original poster" or "original post".  In any case, I forgot to mention but I wrote my code in Python v3.2 so version errors may be an issue.  Thanks for the catch!